# Update main window DOM from other window in electron js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, desktop-application, electron

Let's take a TODO app as example, there is a Main window - A, that will list all of the TODO items and a button 'Add Item'. So when click on the 'Add Item' , it will open up a second window - B, where there is a form for adding item. After the form is submitted, the newly added item will be append to the list in WIndow A.

So the problem here is, how can I update the Item list in WIndow A when when WIndow B form is submitted? I am using react js for the renderer. So, how can react component listen to the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got the answer. 
Turn out we can use webContents to send the message to the desired window. And that message can be listened in the window.

```
#main.js

mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
mainWindow.webContents.send('addingitem','...blahblah balh ');
```

and in render

```
ipc.on("addingitem", (event, arg)=>{
     //doing the update DOM here.
}
```